# Prove the complement of a point in $\mathbb{A}^n$ is compact.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am learning algebraic geometry and I came across the folowing question.  Prove that the complement of a point is compact in $\mathbb{A}^n$.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Open sets are complements of solutions of polynomial equations. Covering $\mathbb{A}^n\setminus\{a\}$ with open sets, is the same as having closet sets with intersection $\{a\}$. So we have infinitely many equations with solution set $\{a\}$. By Hilbert's there are finitely many of them that define have the same solution. Take the open sets they are associated with.

Comment: @QiL'8 In most Topology textbooks compact is just having the finite intersection property, but in Commutative Algebra like in Atiyah Macdonald quasi-compact means a compact non-hausdorff space, so in Atiyah notation he meant quasi-compact

Answer (score 9):

Hint: A space is Noetherian if and only if every subset of the space is compact.